# how to use javascript to extract numeric part of a url

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript to extract a numeric part of a url. There is only ever supposed to be one set of numerals (aka - it will never be www.example.com/455/all/6). The set of numerals will not always be the same. How can I do this? I know that i can use this code

```
    var urlPath = window.location.pathname;
```

to extract the url, but I don't know how to go further.

Comment: Will the numbers always be at the same location in the URL? i.e. www.example.com/123/somethingelse ?

Comment: Yes, that they should always be at the same location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`urlPath.match(/\d+/)[0]` will get the numbers. It doesn't perform any sanity checks, though, and will fail if there are no numbers at all. For better results, try:

```
var t = urlPath.match(/\d+/);
t = t ? t[0] : null; // or some other default value, such as `0`
```

Comment: Thats seems to be what I need. Thanks!